# Tridion RTF Links with special characters in title fails

Tags: tridion

In an RTF field we link to a Component that has a title like 'A Component [1234]'.

Our Compound Template uses the Default Finish Actions TBB.

It fails during publishing with the error:

Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed, Could not transform tcdl file ...\index.aspx, Could not transform tcdl input string Unable to transform input string, Unbalanced attribute quotes linkAttributes=" title="A Component <1234 Source (32526)"

We are also using the Razor mediator but I am guessing it is not relevant here?

Any ideas on why this issue occurs?

Comment: Does it work when using the default Templates (and TBBs) or when using a different title (without square brackets)? in that case I would think it is related to the Razor mediator or the TBBs you use. Anyways it seems your square bracket is somewhere replaced by a less-then sign which is clearly not acceptable in that location, so I would try and find out what is doing that replace.

Comment: It does work without square brackets

Comment: When you look in the Template Builder, what is the contents of the Output item after the Razor View TBB? Does that contain the square brackets or does it have them replaced?

Comment: With DWT templates, DWT actually encodes all the funky characters, so in your case you'd get a &lt; after the DWT TBB runs.  So in your case, check the Razor mediator.  I think this is relevant indeed.  If you don't want to change its code, then you'll need to run your title through an encode function in a TBB before Default Finish Actions starts doing its magic.

Comment: Very good points!  Will look into the Razor mediator output...

Comment: Razor mediator works perfect.  Problem was in a custom RTF function processing the value of the RTF.  Razor does the ResolveXHTML out of the box without us having to write it in our code, but we had some basic RegEx replacement for our field.  Thanks to everyone for the ideas...

Comment: please post that solution as an answer and accept it, maybe it can be useful to other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor mediator works perfect. Problem was in a custom RTF function processing the value of the RTF. Razor does the ResolveXHTML out of the box without us having to write it in our code, but we had some basic RegEx replacement for our field. Thanks to everyone for the ideas.